# What causes closed questions to appear (or reappear) in the 'Reopen Votes' review queue?

Tags: support, closing, reopen, reviewing

As I was reading this meta post: [Why are moderators or high-rep users quick to vote-close a question on Arqade?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994/4797), some of the comments there got me thinking: **What causes closed questions to appear (or reappear) in the ['Reopen Votes' review queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen)?** (for users with enough rep to cast reopen votes)

[An answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7000/4797) here  has stated that "*If the owner comes back and edits their closed question, it will automatically go into a reopen queue.*", and a [comment on it](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6999/what-causes-closed-questions-to-appear-or-reappear-in-the-reopen-votes-revie#comment19047_7000) replied that "*We're not so concerned with dupes, but rather NARQ and Not Constructive. Does [that] apply to everything?*"

So does that answer mean that edits in all types of closed questions will put a closed question in the Reopen Votes' queue or does that apply to certain types of closed questions only? Also, after one has reviewed a closed question in the 'Reopen Votes' queue and has decided to 'Leave it closed', will another edit or reopen vote after that put it back in the 'Reopen Votes' queue?

An answer in [this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/162827) says:

> ...if enough people (currently 3) select "[Leave Open]" within the review queue, the question will be immediately removed from the queue (not shown to any more reviewers)...

Will further edits or reopen votes after a question gets 3 "leave closed" votes make a question re-appear in the 'Reopen Votes' review queue?

Comment: +1 For a very good question.  I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: Flags certainly don't put them into the reopen queue; there's no "reopen" flag. Pretty sure edits bump them into the queue, [some supporting evidence here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163173/166936) though it stops short of saying edits themselves will put a post in the queue

Comment: The simplest thing that causes them to appear in the reopen queue is a vote to reopen, but you're taking that as given and uninteresting, right?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, I mean besides that. I've edited my question further to ask about those other cases.

Answer (score 2):

From the MSO post about changes to ["Close as Duplicate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) (emphasis in original):

> So here are the changes we made:
>
> 1. We've changed the instructions everywhere to indicate that the answers to the original question must solve the dupe’s problem. **That
>      means that the original must have an answer <sup>†</sup>**
> 2. When a question gets closed as dupe, instead of just saying "Possible duplicate", we now indicate "This question already has an
>      answer here".
> 3. If the owner comes back and edits their closed question, it will automatically go into a reopen queue. There's even special UI to
>      compare before and after and see what changed.
> 4. The "Close-as-dupe" popup now makes it much easier to find dupes with answers by allowing you to search and preview questions and
>      answers within the popup.
> 5. We now show "[duplicate]" in the question title everywhere, instead of "[closed]".
>
> <sup>†</sup> There are some exceptions to the requirement that the
>   original have answers. First, mods can close as dupe of anything, to
>   handle any special cases. Second, you can always close as dupe if it's
>   from the same user, to cover the case of problem users who post the
>   same thing multiple times. Last but not least, this check is disabled
>   on meta.

Comment: We're not so concerned with dupes, but rather NARQ and Not Constructive.  Does change 3 apply to everything?

Comment: @MBraedley That's a good question. I had initially assumed that the reopening rules would be the same for questions closed for any reason. Now that I think about it, though - if closing rules are different for each reason then their reopening rules may also be different.